# Microsoft.Extensions.Options Do you have to keep passing it through the full stack manually

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config, appsettings

I'm implementing *appsettings.json* in place of *app.config* for the first time so please excuse the potentially stupid question to which I have not been able to find a satisfactory solution in my research.

I have a solution fronted by a .Net Core 2.0 Web API with dependent projects breaking my solution up into layers of class libraries. I need to get to the connection string stored in my top layer *appsettings.json* (under my Web API) from the bottom persistence layer class library.

I found [this article](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/asp-net-core-step-by-step-guide-to-access-appsettings-json-in-web-project-and-class-library/) explaining it step by step. and finally got it to work.

***Note:*** I tested this functionality with the connectionString but I need other variables as well which I was planning to do later.

My question is that once I implemented the required constructor:

```
public Data(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
{
  ConnectionStrings = connectionStrings;
}
```

I have to manually pass the `IOptions` object all the way through the stack.

```
Data date = new Data(ConnectionStrings);
```

Is there no solution similar to what `ConfigurationManager` gave you that does not require me to pass the `IOptions` object all the way through?

Surely I'm doing something wrong, no?

Comment: No that's the idea - avoid statics/singletons, etc. They make live and testing bad. You should pass them around, if you need to (or parts of it). Also read-up on `IOptionSnapshot`, etc. to understand why statics won't (always) work. Having that said, there is nothing preventing you to "cache" the value once retrieved in a `static` variable and use that from then on (but not recommended, to so say the least).

Comment: @Christian.K, post this as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar concern when I was building my first dotnet core 2 application.  The solution I came up with was to configure dependency injection to resolve `T` as `IOptions<T>.Value`, for example:

```
            services.AddTransient<SomeOptions>(sp => 
                sp.GetService<IOptions<SomeOptions>>().Value);
```

This works well if you are using dependency injection for objects that require SomeOptions to be supplied in the constructor.  Doesn't really provide much value if you are manually "newing" up objects.

I'm not entirely sure what your application looks like, but from your example above you have a `Data` class which takes an `IOptions<ConnectionStrings>` parameter in the constructor.

Given the following code in your startup:

```
// I don't have your entire project - just looking at your link above, I came up with this
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings> 
   (Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));

services.AddTransient<ConnectionStrings>(sp => 
            sp.GetService<IOptions<ConnectionStrings>>().Value);

services.AddTransient<Data>();
```

You could have your Data class defined as such:

```
public class Data
{
    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;

    public Data(ConnectionStrings connectionStrings)
    {
        //I don't know what you need to do with this here - just guessing
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings;
    }
}
```

You could have your controller class defined as such:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly Data _data;

    public SomeController(Data data) 
    {
       _data = data;
    }

    public IActionResult Get() 
    {
        // do something with _data here
        // don't new it up - it gets injected!
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information please? Once I've added services.AddTransiant<... in the startup.cs class of my Web API, how do I access those options from 3 layers down in my persistance class library project?

Comment: Sure - without having all your code, this was the best I could come up with!  Hope that helps you understand Dependency Injection a little better!

Comment: Thanks @BlakeH, but my Data class is actually in a different project. I think Christian.K's answer above is the correct answer from all the reasearch I've done.

Comment: I don't know why a class being in a different project matters at all - but sounds like you have a plan!

Comment: Thanks @BlakeH, I was specifically concerned with having to pass the app settings (including the connection strings) through the constructors of every subsequent project. Based on my past experience with ConfigurationManager, this feels wrong, but I think the reason given by  Christian.K makes sense. Having code in different projects just highlights the question I was trying to address, Thanks anyway